# Can I reuse data that was previously published in a thesis?

Tags: thesis, publishability, data-sharing

Am I allowed to extract data published in a thesis and reanalyze it? I would combine with my own data and the analyses would be much different than the original thesis.

If you have relevant links please share!

Please note this is different from: [Can I use published data by other authors in my study?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122984/can-i-use-published-data-by-other-authors-in-my-study) as it is specifically referring to a thesis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use published data by other authors in my study?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/122984/can-i-use-published-data-by-other-authors-in-my-study)

Comment: Related https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/80002/is-it-ok-to-re-use-data-from-a-previously-publication-in-a-new-publication

Answer (score 5):

**Yes**

There're lots of papers that iterate on publicly-available data. For example, the [MNIST dataset](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/) is a dataset of labelled handwritten digits which different machine learning researchers have attempted to optimize their algorithms on. Similarly, telescopes like the Planck probe produces data which other astronomers use to do their analyses.

There is no prohibition against using data.